# How to send AJAX value as 1 when checkbox is checked and 0 when it is not checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a checkbox it's change text when checked (check is text = on, uncheck is text = off and this value are 0 and 1) I want get value 0 or 1 (check get 1 uncheck get 0) by ajax but I confuse in my code

```js
$("#onoff").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#hidden_onoff").text("ON");
  } else {
    $("#hidden_onoff").text("OFF");
  }
});

$('#onoff').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('#hidden_onoff').val('1');
  } else {
    $('#hidden_onoff').val('0');
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: "/on_off",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    onoff: $("#hidden_onoff").val(),
  },
  success: function(data) {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="on_off">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input id="onoff" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
      <label class="checkbox-inline" id="hidden_onoff">ON</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: One issue is that both the form and the input have the ID "onoff". In HTML, [IDs must be unique to the DOM tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page), i.e. cannot be repeated.

Comment: sorry, I have edited my form id. but my ajax not get value

Comment: What triggers this ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `value` of `<label id="hidden_onoff">` rather than `<input id="onoff">`:

```
$('#hidden_onoff').val('1');
```

However, since you're using AJAX, it doesn't seem that you need to change the input's value anyway. You can define a variable based on whether the input is checked, and send that variable's value to the server.

Also, it doesn't seem that you need both `click` and `change` handlers. You can use the `change` event alone. If your intent is to change the input when its text is clicked, I suggest wrapping both the input and text elements in a `<label>`.

> ... you can nest the `<input>` directly inside the `<label>`, in which case the for and id attributes are not needed because the association is implicit  ([label @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label))

Finally, it looks like you're executing the AJAX upon page load rather than upon input change. I recommend executing the AJAX from inside your event handler.

Here's a demonstration:

```js
// select the input and label elements and store them as constants
const $onoff = $('#onoff');
const $label = $('#onoff_label');

// bind a change event handler to the input
$onoff.on('change', function() {

  // define value and label (1 and ON, or 0 and OFF)
  let cbox_value = $onoff.is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
  let cbox_label = cbox_value ? 'ON' : 'OFF';

  // set label text (ON or OFF)
  $label.text(cbox_label);

  // send value via AJAX (0 or 1)
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      onoff: cbox_value
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // show the result from server
      console.log(data.onoff);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input id="onoff" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span id="onoff_label">ON</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st:** ID must be unique don't use same id for more than one element

**2nd:** `$("#hidden_onoff")` is a `label` so it has a `.text()` not `.val()`

**3rd:** You can use one element event to trigger another element event it will be easier to work with

Take a look at this sample code .. *Changing ids to form_onoff and text_onoff*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#text_onoff").on( 'click' ,function() {
    $('#onoff').prop('checked' , $('#onoff').prop('checked') ? false : true).change();
  });

  $('#onoff').on('change', function(){
    $(this).val(this.checked ? '1' : '0');
    $("#text_onoff").text(this.checked ? 'ON' : 'OFF');
    
    console.log($('#onoff').val());
    
    /*$.ajax({
      url:"/onoff",
      method:"POST",
      data:{ onoff:$("#onoff").val()},
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data)
      }
    });*/
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="form_onoff" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline" >
      <input id="onoff" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1"/>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" id="text_onoff">
          ON
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a loop for all the input of type check

```
$('input[type="check"]').each(function(){
        $(this).val(($(this).prop('checked'))?1:0);
 });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).